# unable to build UI if the function is called from object of a class

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a function to create the UIButton. I am calling that method in the same class using the object of its class.

If I call that function using its object, no UI is created. if I call that method as just `self.createbutton()` button is created.

```
class myClass: UIViewController {
  let mainview     = UIStackView()
  func createbutton() {
    let loadpageview = UIStackView()
    loadpageview.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical
    loadpageview.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.equalSpacing
    loadpageview.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.center
    loadpageview.tag = 30
    loadpageview.spacing   = 16.0

    let buttn = UIButton()
    buttn.backgroundColor = .gray
    buttn.setTitle("testttt", for: .normal)
    buttn.frame.size.height = 30
    buttn.frame.size.width = 40
    buttn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginaction), for: .touchUpInside)

    loadpageview.addArrangedSubview(buttn)    
    mainview.addArrangedSubview(loadpageview)
  }

  func mainviewlet() {
    mainview.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical
    mainview.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.equalSpacing
    mainview.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.center
    mainview.spacing   = 16.0
    mainview.tag = 50

    mainview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    self.view.addSubview(mainview)
  }
}
```

If I create the object of the above class and call `createbutton()` , it wont work

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  self.mainviewlet()
  let pl = myClass()
  pl.createbutton()
}
```

It works, if I call the method as follows :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  self.mainviewlet()
  self.createbutton()
}
```

What's wrong here ? How can I call the method using its object. Further I am calling it from another class. Hence I need this. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

In first example You are creating another instance of `myClass()` and a method in that reference will be called. But you want your Button created in `current` instance of the Class.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.mainviewlet()
      let pl = myClass()
      pl.createbutton()
    }
```

But in working example you are referring current instance of the Class. So the UIButton it is creating is visible.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  self.mainviewlet()
  self.createbutton()
}
```

Its Simple OOPS

Happy Coding

Comment: how can I make it work with another instance ? is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

To make it work with instance of another class create  your view in separate class say MyView. Then create  a function which will return your
 required view. Then call this function from your view controller on the object of that class , you will get your view, in your case it's UIStackView, finally add this as subview of the main view of the view controller.

```
Class MyView:NSObject{

    func createbuttonWith(stackView:UIStackView) {
      let loadpageview = UIStackView()
      loadpageview.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical
      loadpageview.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.equalSpacing
      loadpageview.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.center
      loadpageview.tag = 30
      loadpageview.spacing   = 16.0

      let buttn = UIButton()
      buttn.backgroundColor = .gray
      buttn.setTitle("testttt", for: .normal)
      buttn.frame.size.height = 30
      buttn.frame.size.width = 40
      buttn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginaction), for: .touchUpInside)

    loadpageview.addArrangedSubview(buttn)    
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(loadpageview)
    }

    func mainviewlet()->UIStackView {
     let mainView =  UIStackView()

     mainview.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical
     mainview.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.equalSpacing
     mainview.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.center
     mainview.spacing   = 16.0
     mainview.tag = 50

     mainview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
      return mainView
    } 
}
```

Then in your view controller's viewDidLoad(),

```
let myView =  MyView()
let mainViewLet =  myView.mainviewlet()
self.view.addSubview(mainViewLet)
myView.createbuttonWith(mainViewLet)
```